# ¿Como cortar los bordes de arriba y abajo de un div con css?

Tags: html, css

Necesito cortar los bordes de un div en el border-top and border-bottom. Adjunto imagen del resultado esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que he logrado hacer es cortar los bordes pero de los lados, de esta forma:

```
<div class="box">
  <h1>Prueba</h1>
</div>
```

```
.box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-image: linear-gradient(#000 30%, transparent 0 70%,#000 0) 2;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Daniixhc/pen/abyaOaB

Espero sus comentarios, gracias!

Comment: La imagen que provees es el resultado esperado o como lo tienes actualmente? Deberías probar con   `margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;` en vez de `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: La imagen es como debería quedar. Con los  `margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto; ` se cumple la misma función que con el  `margin: 0 auto ` al final es  para centrar el div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es como lo estabas haciendo con el linear-gradient, solo que es mas ajetreo.

Usas el linear gradient para dibujar el borde sobre un borde blanco o transparente. En el sector que quieres el borde, lo pintas, en donde no lo quieres, no haces nada.

```css
h1 {
  /* dibujas el borde */
  border: solid 3px transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) no-repeat, linear-gradient(to left, black 45%, #cea87c00 45%, #cea87c00 55%, black 55%);
  
  /* lo achicas y centras */
  width:max-content;
  margin:1em auto;
  padding:0.25em 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>PRUEBA</h1>
<h1>TESTEO TESTEO</h1>
```

Comment: oooh perfecto! si me gustaria entender bien así que puedo esperar ah que lo edites cuando puedas. Otra y última consulta si quisiera hacerlo con un  `border-radius: 20px ` es posible de la misma forma ?

Comment: Si, es posible, puedes añadirlo a tu borde, o a un contenedor que contenga los textos. Hay varias formas de hacerlo.